# How run excel on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, azure

I'm implementing a new application in ASP.NET with MVC4. I'd like to use Azure to host my project.
I've already created a cloud, but I have a problem with my datasheet. I'm using a excel file whom calculates some prices. I tryed to use openXML, but it can't recalculate my sheet, so i can't use it.

Then, I was thinking to install Microsoft Excel on my cloud to run my excel file.

Do you have any different ideas? Could my solution work?

Comment: You should be able to boot up a VM on azure and do it that way.  Not sure how clean it would be. There is at least one product out there that uses excel for generating reports.  It is called VantagePoint, from RockwellAutomation, so server side excel does work.

Comment: Actually, I have: SQL database, Storage and Cloud Service. Should I add a Virtual Machine in my Azure Portal?

Comment: As bendataclear said, avoid it like the plague if at all possible.  Just because it CAN be done, doesn't mean it SHOULD be done.  I would exhaust all other possibilities first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advice against running Office on a server apply doubly to Azure. The short answer is consistently "Don't do it". I replied to a [similar question a couple of years ago, and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87576/does-anyone-have-a-good-example-of-controlling-multiple-excel-instances-from-a/90833) still applies. (Use a native .NET library)

Comment: ..this is a good idea, but the conversion effort would be big for me.

Comment: One could argue that a VM centric environment like Azure would be a good place to host a non-server centric software like Excel. The idea is to keep only excel on a machine of its own and start it for every big calculation. This way one would have a machine in a quite know state. If it crashes - kill the whole machine and start a new one. If the CPU runs amok - kill the whole machine and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would avoid this like the plague.

Unless you're doing a crazy amount of calculations in the Excel sheet, it's likely going to be easier to translate the calculation to an asp list or local sql instance than try to get manipulating Excel via Azure asp working.

If you can give details on what happens in the sheet we can probably help to find a way around the problem.

**Edit:**

It seems like you may be forced to use Excel, if so the following Microsoft KB article has a long list of problems and possible workarounds for manipulating Excel files server side:

[**Considerations for server-side Automation of Office**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: yes, unfortunatly I have a crazy amount of calculations and data. I can't replace this file with anything else.

Comment: @gorgonzola as bendataclear said, we need some more details to provide any help. What have you tried?

Comment: I just tryed to use openXML, but it can't recalculate excel after i have inserted my cells' values. So, i have to use Excel environment, i think.

Comment: Well done!..http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/ is a good solution..it works very well!..i don't need license to use only libreries, right?

Comment: @gorgonzola Someone has to develop the solution which is hosted on Azure. You won't have to pay for the instances which run on Azure (that's redistribution of your app), but you do have to pay for the one you install on your developer environment. Note, that I don't work for SpreadSheetGear, but that's how I interpret their licensing policy. It's a very good tool IMHO, worth the money.